# VSCode Remote ssh refuses to connect to one particular server, while connections to other servers work fine

Tags: linux, ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Below is what I *thought* was a fix. However, it's merely a temporary fix and not a fix for the root cause so it happens again.

I have to disclose though, that I'm actually opening up 2 VSCode instances at the same time to connect to two different servers. These two servers' home/[my name] directory is synced and whatever change happens in one server will be reflected to the other.

Could it be this environment that's causing this retry connection issue? I can only make wild guesses.

---

Upon an extensive search, I found an easy solution to resolve the issue.

It is due to the wrong cache at the remote so you have to erase `.vscode-server/` (or `.vscode-server-insiders/`) directory.
Once it's removed, the connection will work again.

Source: https://wendys.tistory.com/166 (Korean)

---

- VSCode Version: 1.47.3
- Local OS Version: Windows 10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041
- Remote OS Version: NAME="Ubuntu" / VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
- Remote Extension/Connection Type: SSH
- Steps to Reproduce:

Trying to connect to ssh server that worked fine days ago.

VSCode Remote extension will keep **retrying** connection and then give up after about 20 tries.

- Does this issue occur when you try this locally?:

  - NO
- Does this issue occur when you try this locally and all extensions are disabled?:

  - Didn't check but another ssh connection is working fine.

Below is the error log that fails to connect.
I read the log but have no idea what's really happening.

Two funny things about this issue:

1. It worked days ago. Just fine.
2. ssh connection to another server works just fine. Only happening on this server and my configuration file has the exact same settings.

I don't have the slightest clue why this is happening.

```
[22:44:18.860] Log Level: 2
[22:44:18.866] remote-ssh@0.51.0
[22:44:18.866] win32 x64
[22:44:18.869] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+ngppms001", attempt 1
[22:44:18.869] SSH Resolver called for host: ngppms001
[22:44:18.870] Setting up SSH remote "ngppms001"
[22:44:18.889] Using commit id "91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e" and quality "stable" for server
[22:44:18.890] Install and start server if needed
[22:44:18.894] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[22:44:19.096] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
[22:44:19.097] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:44:19.100] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:44:22.899] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:44:22.899] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:44:22.924] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:44:22.939] > Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
[22:44:33.954] > 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:44:33.954] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:44:33.954] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:44:34.242] "install" terminal command done
[22:44:34.242] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:44:34.986] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:44:34.987] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:44:37.438] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:44:37.438] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:44:37.465] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
[22:44:37.481] > Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:44:37.496] > Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
[22:44:37.512] > Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
> 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:44:37.512] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:44:37.513] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:44:38.017] "install" terminal command done
[22:44:38.018] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:44:38.527] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:44:38.529] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:44:40.967] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:44:40.967] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:44:41.003] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:44:41.022] > Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 

[22:44:56.627] > Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
[22:44:56.777] > 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:44:56.778] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:44:56.778] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:44:57.061] "install" terminal command done
[22:44:57.061] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:44:57.792] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:44:57.793] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:00.222] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:00.222] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:00.247] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
[22:45:00.263] > \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:45:00.279] > Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
[22:45:00.294] > Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
> 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:00.294] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:00.294] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:00.739] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:00.739] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:01.311] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:01.313] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:03.736] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:03.736] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:03.764] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
[22:45:03.779] > Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:45:03.795] > Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
[22:45:03.959] > 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:03.959] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:03.959] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:04.247] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:04.248] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:04.965] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:04.966] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:07.384] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:07.384] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:07.417] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
[22:45:07.432] > \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:45:07.449] > Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
[22:45:07.617] > Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
> 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:07.617] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:07.617] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:07.907] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:07.907] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:08.633] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:08.634] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:11.063] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:11.064] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:11.097] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:45:11.117] > Found running server...
> 
> *
[22:45:11.131] > * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
[22:45:11.144] > 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:11.144] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:11.144] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:11.425] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:11.425] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:12.158] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:12.159] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:14.600] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:14.600] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:14.635] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:45:14.654] > Found running server...
> 
> *
[22:45:14.666] > * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[22:45:18.165] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
[22:45:18.461] > \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
> Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
[22:45:18.468] > 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:18.469] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:18.469] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:18.786] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:18.786] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:19.480] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:19.482] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:22.122] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:22.123] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:22.144] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:45:22.190] > Found running server...
[22:45:22.256] > 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
[22:45:22.331] > 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:22.331] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:22.331] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:22.678] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:22.678] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:23.339] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:23.340] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:25.780] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:25.780] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:25.816] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:45:25.834] > Found running server...
> 
> *
[22:45:25.848] > * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
[22:45:26.007] > 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:26.007] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:26.007] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:26.365] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:26.365] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:27.025] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:27.026] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:29.453] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:29.453] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:29.486] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:45:29.504] > Found running server...
> 
> *
[22:45:29.517] > * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
> 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:29.518] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:29.518] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:29.965] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:29.965] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:30.526] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:30.527] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:32.980] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:32.981] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:32.986] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[22:45:33.025] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
[22:45:33.035] > \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:45:33.047] > Found running server...
> 
> *
[22:45:33.063] > * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
> 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:33.063] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:33.064] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:33.601] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:33.601] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:34.081] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:34.082] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:36.524] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:36.525] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:36.556] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:45:36.637] > Found running server...
> 
> *
[22:45:36.647] > * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
[22:45:36.670] > Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
[22:45:36.746] > 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:36.747] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:36.747] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:37.063] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:37.063] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:37.762] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:37.763] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:40.199] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:40.200] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:40.239] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
[22:45:40.347] > \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
> Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,  
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057) 
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
> 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:40.348] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:45:40.349] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:45:40.744] "install" terminal command done
[22:45:40.745] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:45:41.360] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:45:41.362] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:45:44.052] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:45:44.053] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:45:44.766] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
[22:45:44.955] > \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
> Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,  
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057) 
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
[22:46:03.265] > 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:46:03.265] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:46:03.265] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:46:03.598] "install" terminal command done
[22:46:03.598] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:46:04.280] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:46:04.281] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:46:06.672] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:46:06.672] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:46:06.707] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:46:06.725] > Found running server...
[22:46:06.740] > 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
> 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:46:06.740] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:46:06.740] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:46:07.226] "install" terminal command done
[22:46:07.226] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:46:07.746] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49917 ngppms001 bash
[22:46:07.747] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:46:10.190] > 4a2e46151d35: running
> �]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe�
[22:46:10.190] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:46:10.224] > Acquiring lock on /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626
> 991a18c8a6a1b3e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8
> a6a1b3e
> \ln /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3
> e/vscode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e.target
>  /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e/v
> scode-remote-lock.jaepillchoi.91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
> Found existing installation at /home/jaepillchoi/.vscode-server/bin/91899dcef7b8
> 110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e...
[22:46:10.243] > Found running server...
> 
> *
[22:46:10.256] > * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 34485 with wget
[22:46:10.416] > 
> 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:46:10.416] Received install output: 4a2e46151d35##28##
[22:46:10.416] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
[22:46:10.767] "install" terminal command done
[22:46:10.767] Install terminal quit with output: 
[22:46:11.424] Resolver error: 
[22:46:11.429] ------
```

Below is the log from the developer console integrated inside VSCode.
[image: Logs from the developer console]

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the target host yet?

Comment: @DanielB No I have not, but have just found a solution from massive search.

Comment: @DanielB No... not solved yet. My solution was just a temporary fix and the root cause was not resolved. Rebooting the target host is not possible since it's a company server.